# ThreeJS Merging multiple meshes with unique materials

Tags: javascript, three.js

I don't know what I'm doing wrong. I have multiple meshes that I am trying to merge into one mesh so that I can save on draw calls.
Each of my meshes has a unique materials. In this example it just has a different color, but really they will have unique textures mapped.

This is my code:

```
        materials = [];
        blocks = [];
        var tempMat;
        var tempCube;
        var tempGeo;
        var tempvec;


        // block 1
        tempMat = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({ color: '0x0000ff' });
        materials.push( tempMat );
        tempGeo = new THREE.CubeGeometry(1, 1, 1);
        for (var ix=0; ix<tempGeo.faces.length; ix++) {
                tempGeo.faces[ix].materialIndex = 0;
        }
        tempCube = new THREE.Mesh( tempGeo, tempMat );
        tempCube.position.set(0, 3, -6);
        blocks.push( tempCube );


        // block 2
        tempMat = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({ color: '0x00ff00' });
        materials.push( tempMat );
        tempGeo = new THREE.CubeGeometry(1, 1, 1);
        for (var ix=0; ix<tempGeo.faces.length; ix++) {
                tempGeo.faces[ix].materialIndex = 1;
        }
        tempCube = new THREE.Mesh( tempGeo, tempMat );
        tempCube.position.set(1, 3, -6);
        blocks.push( tempCube );


        // Merging them all into one
        var geo = new THREE.Geometry();
        for (var i=0; i<blocks.length; i++) {
            blocks[i].updateMatrix();
            geo.merge(blocks[i].geometry, blocks[i].matrix, i);
        }
        var newmesh = new THREE.Mesh( geo, new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial( materials ) );
        scene.add(newmesh);
```

Basically, that gives me an error that says:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'visible' of undefined
every time my render function is called.

Where did I go wrong?

Comment: You could have debugged this yourself. (1) The third argument to `Geometry.merge()` is an offset, and should be zero in your case. (2) Specify hex colors without quotes: `THREE.MeshLambertMaterial( { color: 0x00ff00 } )` -- but don't do what you are doing. See answer, instead.

Answer (score 1):

You are merging geometries into one, and using `MeshFaceMaterial` (renamed `MultiMaterial` in r.72).

It does not make any sense to merge geometries having different material indices.

`WebGLRenderer` needs to segment the geometry by material to render it.

As a rule-of-thumb, only merge geometries if they will be rendered with a single material.

three.js r.72

Comment: So, if I have 10,000 Cubes, and each cube has a different texture, then there must be 10,000 draw calls?

Comment: Look, this is what I'm trying to make: http://www.sidequestsapps.com/sandbox_files/blocks/newgrid.html I need to be able to have over 100,000 cubes. Someone recommended chunking them in groups. So I was going to combine 10x10x10 groups of blocks using this method. But it sounds like you're saying I cannot. Then what are my options!? How can I make an entire minecraft world if I can't have more than 10,000 blocks without it halting to 3fps.

Comment: Sorry, I can't design your code for you. I suggest you look at both of the three.js minecraft examples, which are each implemented with a single draw call.

Comment: terrible answer in every way imaginable, the minecraft examples involve MERGING the geometires